# Frontend upload asset to Matrix

Tags: matrix, php, upload

I created a matrix with 1 type, 3 fields for user profile. I use front-end to upload file to documentUpload field. But I got PHP warning: `array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array message`. I Google it and see [this issue](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms/issues/29). I did try adding

```
if (empty($value)) {
    $value = array();
}
```

But I still got the same issue. Not sure how I could resolve the issue. I see my file is uploaded to AWS S3. Looks it has issue to save it in Craft. Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks

Here is my code to upload file:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {{ getCsrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
<input type="hidden" name="fields[petRecords][new{{ next }}][type]" value="records">
<input type="hidden" name="fields[petRecords][new{{ next }}][enabled]" value="1">
<input type="file" name="fields[petRecords][new{{ next }}][fields][documentUpload]" />
<input type="text" name="fields[petRecords][new{{ next }}][fields][description]" />
<input type="text" name="fields[petRecords][new{{ next }}][fields][petIdNumber]" />
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-social" type="submit" value="continue">
</form>
```

[image: configuration]
My Craft CMS version is 2.6.2980
[image: Error message]

Comment: Have you tried passing your file field as an array, adding `[]` at the end?`fields[petRecords][new{{ next }}][fields][documentUpload][]`

Comment: You're linking to an [amforms plugin](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms/issues/29) issue. Is this an amforms form?  Doesn't look like it because it's calling `users/saveUser`.

Comment: @matt-stein, Adding `[]` looks that issue is gone. but when I enter another file, I got error. After I refresh my page and add the file again, it allows me to add a file. Looks the tagetID is not loaded on the first time.

Comment: `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'targetId' cannot be null. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `craft_relations` (`fieldId`, `sourceId`, `sourceLocale`, `targetId`, `sortOrder`, `dateCreated`, `dateUpdated`, `uid`) VALUES (:row0_col0, :row0_col1, NULL, NULL, :row0_col4, :row0_col5, :row0_col6, :row0_col7). Bound with :row0_col0='98', :row0_col1='522', :row0_col4=1, :row0_col5='2017-05-26 18:22:39', :row0_col6='2017-05-26 18:22:39', :row0_col7='75187a4d-f2fc-4389-9c35-f42b9ba1f17c'`

Comment: @BradBell, I'm not using amforms, looks I am on the wrong direction.

Comment: If I'm following you, @AngelaChan, you would also need to add `multiple` to your field if you're attempting to add more than one file to it. Example [here in P&T's docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields#uploading-files-from-front-end-entry-forms).

Comment: I see your new question [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20603/cdbexception-error-when-upload-files-to-matrix-field-on-front-end), @AngelaChan. Can you add the `[]` fix as an answer to this one in case other people might have the same issue?